# PKI Path Validation in Java

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, pki, truststore

I am trying to learn the basics of PKI and path validation. I have also looked at the JDK implementation of PKI path validation ([RFC 5280 6.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5280#section-6.1)). Unfortunately, I don't understand why it is sufficient to have the server certificate and not a CA certificate in the truststore. As i understood the entire certification path from/to the trust anchor would have to be processed for path validation to succeed. So am I misunderstanding something here?

Thanks,
Hector

Comment: In Java a cert path is accepted if it either chains _to_ an anchor _OR_ if the last cert in the path _is_ itself an anchor (and the rest chain to it) -- which occurs if a chain is sent with/including its root; Java applies the latter rule even when there is only one cert and it is not a CA, because it is has become common to use self-signed EE certs for dev and test even though 5280 as written doesn't cover this case. This might be called an extension. (For comparison, OpenSSL by default accepts an EE cert that is in the truststore but only if it is self-signed.)